# Python - Process call and wait

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I got a question about calling a process and wait till this program is closing.

It should work like this:

Main program and secondary program.

The Main program should open the secondary program by clicking on a QPushButton.

Then the secondary program appears and you can normaly use it.

In the moment you close it, ( so the process get killed, by exiting the window) the main program should get terminated too.

I know there is the module "subprocess", but I do not understand how to use it. The documentation is a bit weired.

Thx for help :)

Comment: Why not simply close the first program immediately after opening the second one? Do you really need to interact with the first program whilst the second one is running? If so, this will complicate things, because the simplest solutions will block the first process while waiting for the second process to finish.

Comment: @ekhumoro Well this works too. The first program is just the executer. After my first program started the second one, the first can get closed. It does not play any role if its open or closed. How would you do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
    import subprocess
    subprocess.call('ping 192.168.132.133')
```

In Python 3.X, you use subprocess.run() which is preferred.
If you want for more advanced cases that run() can not work, you can use popen() directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to keep the first program running, you can just close it immediately after opening the second program:

```
    if QtCore.QProcess.startDetached('prog2', ['arg1', 'arg2']):
        QtWidgets.qApp.quit()
    else:
        print('ERROR: could not start prog2')
```